# Spring + Vue любой запрос HTTP ERROR 404

Tags: java, vue.js, http, webpack

В ходе некоторых изменений в коде контроллеров полностью перестало работать приложение, на любой запрос возвращается **HTTP ERROR 404**, причем **откат на версию до изменений так же не работает**,  как и на любые другие версии, в которых все работало. В настройках `WebMvcConfig` все настроено и прекрасно работало, никаких изменений не вносил, на попытки изменить конфигурацию в `WebSecurityConfig` никакой реакции, уже пробовал все, вплоть до полного удаления Spring Security из проекта. Даже пытался собрать новый проект из кода с версии где все работало, результат тот же самый, причем даже полностью без всего бекенда и вообще без Security, результат тот же самый: **HTTP ERROR 404**
[image: Вывод в браузере]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
По видимому проблема с файлом `index.html`, так как он приходит пустым, отднако попытки изменить его расположение на любой другой внутри `src/recourses`так же безрезультатны, либо проблема с `webpack` так как при запросе нет никаких других запросов в браузере, кроме `/`

Cамое интересное то, что НИКАКИХ ИЗМЕНЕНИЙ В КОДЕ ФРОНТЕНДА И ВЕБПАКА НЕ БЫЛО, оно просто перестало работать на ровном месте, после изменения когда, совершненно не связанного в загрузкой страниц, до этого все работало отлично очень долгое время

Я надеюсь кто нибудь может помочь с этой ситуаций, у кого была схожая проблема или же хотя бы определить причину или направление, в котором нужно копать, вот код ключевых элементов проекта:

**структура проекта**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.js**

```
import Vue          from 'vue'
import VueResource  from 'vue-resource'
import router       from "./router";
import App          from "pages/App.vue"
import Vuetify      from "vuetify";
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vuesax       from 'vuesax'
import VueMask      from 'v-mask'
import store from 'store'

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(Vuesax);
Vue.use(VueMask);
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    router,
    store,
    render: a => a(App)
});
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue          from 'vue';
import VueRouter    from "vue-router";
import Home         from "pages/Catalog.vue";
import Admin        from "pages/Admin.vue";
import Order        from "pages/Order.vue";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Home},
    {path: '/order', component: Order},
    {path: '/admin', component: Admin},
];
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PleaseDo</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@3.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="http://localhost:8000/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'js', 'main.js'),
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        disableHostCheck: true,
        compress: true,
        port: 8000,
        allowedHosts: ['localhost:9000']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?\S*)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
            {test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [{loader: 'file-loader',},],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()],
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'resources', 'static', 'js'),
            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
        ],
    }
}
```

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableWebServerFactory> webServerCustomizer() {
        return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/"));
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {   
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/js/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").permitAll()//!!!hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                    .mvcMatchers("/api/user/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/user/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/user/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout().permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```